# how to read 3 json responses like one

Tags: json

I have 3 functions that invoke a json response

function one gives:

```
{
    "IT_INFO": {
        "CARNET": "999250 ",
        "CEDULA": "000013724224",
        "NOMBRE": "pedro ",
        "SEGNOMBRE": "salomon ",
        "APELLIDO": "Perez ",
        "SEGAPELLIDO": "Perza ",
        "EMAIL": "mail@mailexample.com ",
        "IAP": "0.00",
        "IAA": "0.00"
    }
}
```

second function :

```
{
    "HISTORICOP": [
        {
            "MATERIA": "PROCESOS DEL LENGUAJE ",
            "NOTA": "7 ",
            "ANIO": "2000",
            "PERIODO": "001",
            "ENEMENOSUNO": "Ordinaria. Estado por defecto "
        }
    ]
}
```

third function:

```
{
    "HORARIO": [
        {
            "CODIGO": "BERSP01 ",
            "MATERIA": " COMPUTADOR ",
            "AULA": "A1-102 ",
            "PROFESOR": "Quintero Moros, Nelson ",
            "HORARIO": "TU WE FR 08:00-10:00 "
        }
    ]
}
```

How should it come out so the function `JSON.parse(str)` will read it?

```
str = [func1,func2,func3] ??
```

or

```
str = [[func1],[func2],[func3]]?
```

or??? any ideas???

Comment: Please format the JSON properly so that others can get a grasp of its structure more easily. http://jsonlint.com/ is great for formatting (valid) JSON.

Comment: you made my day just by showing me http://jsonlint.com/!!!!! awesome tool!!! thaaaaaanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you parse the JSON in JavaScript.

Normally you should not build JSON "manually", but in this case it does not seem to be too bad:

```
var objs = JSON.parse('[' + [func1(), func2(), func3()].join(',') + ']');
```

This creates a JSON array with the three objects returned by the functions.

Alternatively you can parse the responses individually:

```
var objs = [func1(), func2(), func3()];
for(var i = objs.length; i--; ) {
   objs[i] = JSON.parse(objs[i]);
}
```

---

Of course you have to do things differently if the functions don't return the JSON but make some Ajax request...